# jQuery offset or position

Tags: jquery, html, css

o a, tryng to position a div exactly where the browser top menu ends and the user starts to see the page, ie, i want it's margin-top to be the amount of pixels the user has scrolled down.

Can you help me with this please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do that simply with CSS using absolute positioning or position: fixed

Answer (score 1):

Would `position:fixed` be an option for you? [example](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/vmq3S/1/)